# VISIO - How to set grid lines such that each character appears in 1 square and each square contains only 1 character using fixed font

Tags: visio

What I am trying to do is to enable the user to fill a report design form using fixed font. Only older people have seen such forms for coding and report design :)

Question:
Using VISIO, how to set grid lines such that each character appears in 1 square and each square contains only 1 character using a fixed font such as Courier New? I am open to completely different approaches if any, even if it involves coding in VBA or C#, I know some.

I tried different values for "Minimum Spacing" but I can't get the desired result.
[image]

EDIT

I also attempted to place a grid image in the background and put the textbox in front, still monospaced font characters overlap with lines...

[image]

Edit I also tried this VBA Code:

```
Sub Test()
Dim I As Integer
Dim D As Double
Dim X1 As Double
Dim Y1 As Double

D = 0.13
X1 = 1.373
Y1 = 10.04

For I = 1 To 20
    Application.ActiveWindow.Page.DrawLine X1, Y1, X1, Y1 + 1

    X1 = X1 + D
        Next
    End Sub
```

Which produced the following "bad" result - All this suggests the the implementation of Courier New is not really fixed in width!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visio grid doesn't work in that way. You need to use a proper grid shape. There is one at **More Shapes** -> **Business** -> **Charts and Graphs** -> **Charting Shapes**. Set the columns and rows to what you need and then resize.

Example here - using font Liberation Mono.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks like my VISIO 2007 is too old for this trick. I could upgrade. Would be at all possible to attach a picture of the result? Would characters be typed naturally in the keyboard? Thanks.

Comment: Visio 2007 - menu File -> Shapes ...

Comment: I got it. You mean that I should use the GRID shape. There are 2 issues in my case with this shape. You can't naturally type text in, you need to type 1 character in each cell. Also, max. columns is 10 only. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Put the grid on a background page, make this background page the background for your page, and put a normal shape onto the foreground page, then make this shape transparent so the grid shows through.

Comment: Paul, sounds like a good idea. I am trying this.

Comment: Paul, I tried your suggestion, but for some reasons, the characters overlap the grid lines after some characters. I though that monospaced fonts should hold equal width! Please see my edited quesiton.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example. What font are you using?

Comment: File is at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n250xejtcn9dzxc/textOnGrid.vsd?dl=0

Comment: Excellent, thanks much for your help.

Comment: Above file now removed.

Comment: OK, got it thanks.

Comment: @NoChance - I've added this to my webpage of useful free shapes at https://www.paulherber.co.uk/free-visio-shapes/

Comment: Excellent thanks for sharing this page.